# Updating a 3 Million record table using LEAD() function

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I need to update a `EDW_END_DATE` column in a Dimension table using the `LEAD()` function and the table has 3 Million records , the Oracle query seems to be running forever .

```
UPDATE
  Edwstu.Stu_Class_D A
SET
  EDW_END_DATE =
  (
    SELECT
      Edw_New_End_Dt
    FROM
      (
        SELECT
          LEAD(Edw_Begin_Date-1,1,'31-DEC-2099') over ( PARTITION BY
          Acad_Term_Code ,Class_Number Order By Edw_Begin_Date ASC) AS
          Edw_New_End_Dt,
          STU_CLASS_KEY
        FROM
          Edwstu.Stu_Class_D)
      B
    WHERE
      A.STU_CLASS_KEY = B.STU_CLASS_KEY
);
```

Comment: your sub query returns fast?

Comment: Yes it does return fast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update it using MERGE statement:

```
MERGE INTO EDWSTU.STU_CLASS_D A 
USING (
          SELECT
              LEAD(EDW_BEGIN_DATE - 1, 1, '31-DEC-2099') OVER(
                  PARTITION BY ACAD_TERM_CODE, CLASS_NUMBER
                  ORDER BY
                      EDW_BEGIN_DATE ASC
              ) AS EDW_NEW_END_DT,
              STU_CLASS_KEY
          FROM
              EDWSTU.STU_CLASS_D
      )
B ON ( A.STU_CLASS_KEY = B.STU_CLASS_KEY )
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET A.EDW_END_DATE = B.EDW_NEW_END_DT;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks Tejas for your valuable feedback

Answer (score 0):

You are updating all the rows in the table.  This is generally an expensive operation due to locking and logging.

You might consider regenerating the table entirely.  Note:  before doing this, backup the table.

```
-- create the table with the results you want
create table temp_stu_class_d as
    select d.*, lead(Edw_Begin_Date - 1, 1, date '20199-12-31') as Edw_New_End_Dt
    from Edwstu.Stu_Class_D d;

-- remove the contents of the current table
truncate table Edwstu.Stu_Class_D

insert into Edwstu.Stu_Class_D ( . . . , Edw_End_Dt)  -- list the columns here
    select . . . , Edw_New_End_Dt  -- and here
    from temp_stu_class_d;
```

The `insert` is generally much more efficient than logging each update.

Comment: Thanks Gordon for your Valuable feedback i will work on it